# OSGi can't find the activator

Tags: java, osgi

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Name: Mahjong
Bundle-Activator: MahjongActivator
Bundle-SymbolicName: Mahjong
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

Compiling & jarring:

```
$ javac -classpath equinox.jar src/start/*java
$ jar -cfm Mahjong.jar MahjongManifest.mf src/start/*class
```

The activator:

```
package start;

import org.osgi.framework.*;

public class MahjongActivator implements BundleActivator
{
    public void start(BundleContext context)
    {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
    public void stop(BundleContext context)
    {
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }
}
```

Then I load the .jar in OSGi and when I try to `start()` it, it says:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator MahjongActivator for bundle Mahjong is invalid
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:751)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:276)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MahjongActivator
...
some more ClassNotFounds...
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be "Bundle-Activator: start.MahjongActivator" -- you've omitted the package name.